# Помогите с регулярным выражением на проверку длины

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Проверяю E-mail,всё работает

```
([a-z0-9_\.-]{5,20}+)@([a-z0-9_\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,10})
```

При добавлении проверки на длину после @, перестает корректно работать

```
([a-z0-9_\.-]{5,20}+)@([a-z0-9_\.-]{2,10}+)\.([a-z\.]{2,10})
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: Это плохое регулярное выражение для проверки email. А так: у вас там лишних плюсов полно после `}`.

Comment: объясните почему оно плохое? И не нужно писать что бы я использовал filter_var() \,мне нужна именно регулярка, напишите тогда как правильно

Comment: 1. Потому что на дворе 21 век и давно уже есть домены не только латиницей. 2. Потому что оно не пропустит даже все адреса с гугле-почты и других распространенных сервисов. 3. Потому что оно пропустит почту вида `-----@-----....` :b

Comment: Прочтите это https://habrahabr.ru/post/175375/

Comment: ну меня это не волнует у меня будет мой фиксированный "стандарт" для адресов, меня волнует мой вопрос, может лучше подскажете что изменить в моей регулярке что бы она работала с длиной корректно?

Comment: @Игорь Вам же написали, лишний плюс: `([a-z0-9_.-]{5,20}+)@([a-z0-9_.-]{2,10})\.([a-z.]{2,10})` Ещё совет - внутри символьных классов метасимволы _(кроме знаков "-" и "^")_ обрабатываются так же, как и литералы. То есть, не требуется их экранировать.

Comment: не работает....

Comment: Так работать будет `([a-z0-9_\.-]{5,20})@([a-z0-9_\.-]{2,10})\.([a-z\.]{2,10})`

Comment: @Игорь всё там работает:  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/39102e90a479cd0e9bae757f51e1ddc9333904e1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас весьма странная получилась регулярка, и запутанная.

([a-z0-9_.-]**{5,20}+**)@([a-z0-9_.-]**{2,10}+**).([a-z.]{2,10})

Ваши квантификаторы имеют не явное обозначение, с одной стороны вы говорите, что длинна задаваемого диапазона должна быть от 5 до 20 символов, и далее указываете что она может быть от 1 до ∞.

Для начала, стоит разобраться с квантификаторами, и вероятнее всего, вам подойдет такой вариант:

```
([a-z0-9_\.-]{5,20})@([a-z0-9_\.-]{2,10})\.([a-z\.]{2,10})
```

Но, лучше бы было упростить диапазоны и записать ваше выражение так:

```
([\w.-]{5,20})@([\w.-]{2,10})\.([a-z.]{2,10})
```

Comment: `{5,20}+` вовсе не означает *от 1 до ∞*. Только от 5 до 20.

Answer (score 1):

Для большинства случаев, будет лучше использовать встроенную функцию в php:

```
filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Только это решение не работает с кириллическими символами.